# Use integrator output as matrix input in simulink

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink, ode

I'm trying to solve a set of differential equations in matrix form in simulink. My issue is that the output of 2 of my integrators should be "x" and "y" from each and then I need those x and y values to be put into a matrix in order to solve it. So I'm wondering if I what I'm trying to do isn't possible, or I have the wrong approach for solving the equations.

What I'm trying to solve is:

```
[dx/dt;dy/dt]=[1;0]+[-2,-5;1,0][x;y]
```

and this is the current setup I have:

Any suggestions are appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `x` and `y` are scalars, so given that it's a 2 unknown, 2 equations problem, using matrix notation is over-complicating the problem. It would be much easier to model your system using scalar equations:

```
dx/dt = -2*x - 5*y + 1;
dy/dt = x;
```

which in fact, can be collapsed to 1 unknown, 1 equation system:

```
d^2 x / dt^2 = -2*dx/dt - 5*x;
```

So start with one integrator block, the output of which is `dx/dt` (and the input therefore `d^2 x / dt^2`), and forms the input a second integrator block, which would then output `x`. Close the loop by adding `-5*x` and `-2*dx/dt` and feeding this to the input of the first integrator block. To get `y`, add a third integrator block, with `x` as input, and `y` as output. Don't forget to set the correct initial conditions for each of the integrator blocks.